# Save value to core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm making the simple app for my portfolio and have a problem. There is app like notebook on table view. Through button I'm going to next view controller where I set options, title, text, picture, etc. All this data I save in CoreData. So, I want to create one more option, little window of picture, on which I tap by finger and it change the color (red, green, yellow). And in dependence on it should change the color of cell in my table view. It mean the condition of picture should be saved in coredata, I totally don't understand how to do it.

Comment: please share the code you have, no one will be able to help with just that superficial description.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a set of colour options. This can be cleanly represented as an enumeration. Each enumerate is, under the hood, an integer value, so it can be stored into core data as an int (packed in an `NSNumber`).

If you want to allow arbitrary colours then you need to save the actual RGBA data, either in the color object, as individual values or as some encoded format. `UIColor` supports `NSSecureCoding` so the simplest option is to use a transformable attribute type in core data and then you can simply use the color object and the archiving will be taken care of for you.